# How to add and remove routes dynamically in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo, mojolicious-lite

I am trying to put together a maintenance page in my Mojolicious app which all of my users will be shown whenever a file or DB entry is present on the server.

I know I can check for this  file or entry on startup and if its there add in my 'catch all' route. However I'm not sure how to do this dynamically? I don't want to have to restart the backend whenever I want to go into maintenance.

Is there a way to add and remove routes from a hook? for example use the before dispatch hook to monitor for the file/db entry and if it exists modify the routes?

I tried this but I didn't seem to be able to access the routes from the hooked function, only in the startup function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The router is dynamic until the first request has been served, after that, the router cannot change routes ([source](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Rearranging_routes)). That said, can you not declare the route generally and just prohibit any access until that condition exists?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;

any '/' => sub { shift->render( text => 'Hello World' ) };

under sub { 
  unless (-e 'myfile') {
    shift->render_not_found;
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
};

any '/protected' => sub { shift->render( text => 'I am safe' ) };

app->start;
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. Thats exactly what I was after. I didn't realise it would be so simple!

Comment: `under` is possibly a little tricky to translate to being a full app (rather than lite). In a full app, the `under` method returns a new sub-router (called a bridge), rather than changing the global router as in Lite. Just keep that in mind if you decide to go that way eventually.

Comment: I had a similar issue. There's now a commit that would allow routes to be rearranged at runtime: https://github.com/kraih/mojo/commit/4b9fc41a96aa85b7d342e2135dcc4c53fef0ca18

Comment: Please note that the inclusion of that patch is still a matter of debate. We worry that it might encourage bad design.